# Стили django админки

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Захотел научиться менять стили админки Django. Сделал в своём проекте collectstatic и в корне появилась папка static с папкой admin внутри. В файле base.css внёс некоторые изменения, но стили админки всё равно остаются прежними, хотя, через "исследование элемента" в браузере, показывается, что стили берутся как раз из этого файла. Кто знает в чём проблема?

Comment: Небось `DEBUG=True`?

Comment: Да. Из-за этого что-ли он игнорит мои стили?

Comment: В отладочном режиме статика берётся не из `STATIC_ROOT`, а из каталогов  приложений. Да и лучше не трогать исходную статику.

Comment: Спасибо. А как вообще менять стили админки в отладочном режиме?

Comment: Через [переопределение шаблонов](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Comment: Не имеет значения, в отладочном или нет. Вы не должны никак редактировать появившуюся папку static, потому что должна обновляться только с помощью команды collectstatic и никак иначе. Вы должны редактировать статику внутри приложений, которая и является источником данных для команды collectstatic. // В зависимости от того, какие именно стили вы хотите изменить, можно найти несколько разных способов изменения

Comment: Большое спасибо :)